# Some images are not loaded - 404 not found

Tags: 7, media

Some images on my Drupal site are not loading. In the folder sites/all/default/files and also in the folder sites/all/themes/mytheme/images some images are not loading.

When I rename the file and upload him again, the image is visible. And also when I copy the site to my localhost all images are showing.

I tried to change my settings.php `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` and my .htacces file:

```
The .htaccess file will look like this:

SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

Change it to:
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
#Options None
#Options +FollowSymLink
```

With no luck.

The error:
`The requested URL "/sites/default/files/images/images1.jpg" was not found on this server.`

It's weird that the images wich are linked to my css file are also blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your paths are incorrect.  If you developed the site on your local computer, it's mostly that you a path structure that has changed on your production site.

Based on the error you're receiving I'd also confirm that your site root is what you think it is. The path indicated in your error is <site_root>/sites/default/images/image1.jpg

Comment: I'm sure the path is correct. But thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Options +FollowSymLink to Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch. Don't comment this line. I had similar problem on one shared hosting.